# nft_connlimit on RHEL 8 kernel 4.18

Tags: redhat, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

Does anyone know what happened to nft_connlimit module on RHEL 8 for nftables?
This should be available from Kernel 4.18 onwards but cannot find it anywhere in the available kernel modules.
Because of the lack of this one cannot use 'ct count' in nftables.

Comment: It's not just RHEL. In Fedora 35 I cannot use "ct count" neither (a simple rule like nft add rule ip filter input ct count over 2 log gives me this error: “Error: Could not process rule: No such file or directory”, marking “ct counter 2” as the bad written part of the rule)

My kernel is 5.16.14-200.fc35.x86_64 and nftables package version is last available in Fedora's official repository: v1.0.0

It's a pity